# Load 1024bit P and G value defined in the RFC5114 into boost uint1024

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, boost-multiprecision

I am trying to implement a diffie-hellman key exchange system. For my P and G value, I plan to use the one defined in the [RFC5114 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5114#section-2.1). So I have the following code:

#Code

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
    using namespace boost::multiprecision;
    using namespace std;


    int main(){
        uint1024_t P;

        P = 0xB10B8F96A080E01DDE92DE5EAE5D54EC52C99FBCFB06A3C69A6A9DCA52D23B616073E28675A23D189838EF1E2EE652C013ECB4AEA906112324975C3CD49B83BFACCBDD7D90C4BD7098488E9C219A73724EFFD6FAE5644738FAA31A4FF55BCCC0A151AF5F0DC8B4BD45BF37DF365C1A65E68CFDA76D4DA708DF1FB2BC2E4A4371;

        cout << "P is: " << P << endl;

        cout << "Maximum value for uint1024_t is:" <<std::numeric_limits<uint1024_t>::max() << endl;
    
        return 0;
    }
```

#Output

```
    P is: 16077765716036174705
    Maximum value for uint1024_t is:179769313486231590772930519078902473361797697894230657273430081157732675805500963132708477322407536021120113879871393357658789768814416622492847430639474124377767893424865485276302219601246094119453082952085005768838150682342462881473913110540827237163350510684586298239947245938479716304835356329624224137215
    // that value is equal to 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    // which is larger than the value that i try to assign to P
```

#Warning
warning: integer constant is too large for its type

so...
###What am I doing wrong here? And how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct the integer from a string:

```
uint1024_t P = "0xB10B8F96A080E01DDE92DE5EAE5D54EC52C99FBCFB06A3C69A6A9DCA52D23B616073E28675A23D189838EF1E2EE652C013ECB4AEA906112324975C3CD49B83BFACCBDD7D90C4BD7098488E9C219A73724EFFD6FAE5644738FAA31A4FF55BCCC0A151AF5F0DC8B4BD45BF37DF365C1A65E68CFDA76D4DA708DF1FB2BC2E4A4371";
```

However this will construct the literal at runtime. If you want to have it be constructed at compile time, you can use the user-defined literals provided by boost::multiprecision:

```
constexpr auto P = 0xB10B8F96A080E01DDE92DE5EAE5D54EC52C99FBCFB06A3C69A6A9DCA52D23B616073E28675A23D189838EF1E2EE652C013ECB4AEA906112324975C3CD49B83BFACCBDD7D90C4BD7098488E9C219A73724EFFD6FAE5644738FAA31A4FF55BCCC0A151AF5F0DC8B4BD45BF37DF365C1A65E68CFDA76D4DA708DF1FB2BC2E4A4371_cppui1024;
```

The type of an integer literal in C++ is at most `(unsigned) long long int` (or some larger type if the implementation supports it). In your case the literal is too large and will therefore be narrowed to that type.

See `boost::multiprecision` documentation [part 1](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/conversions.html) and [part 2](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/lits.html).

Comment: I believe that correct syntax is uint1024_t P ("0xFFFFFFFFF"); But you are definitely right. Thank you very much for pointing me to that documentation.